# Combining 4 Bytes To Integer

Tags: java

I have an array of bytes called `contents` from which I want to read bytes, shorts and integers from.

To do this, I read bytes individually and combine them by shifting.

```
public byte getByteValue(int fileOffset)
{
    return contents[fileOffset];
}

public short getShortValue(int fileOffset)
{
    short shortValue;

    shortValue = getByteValue(fileOffset);
    shortValue = (short) (shortValue * 256 + getByteValue(fileOffset + 1));

    return shortValue;
}

public int getIntegerValue(int fileOffset)
{
    int integerValue;

    integerValue = getShortValue(fileOffset);
    integerValue = integerValue * 256 + getByteValue(fileOffset + 2);
    integerValue = integerValue * 256 + getByteValue(fileOffset + 3);

    return integerValue;
}
```

When this is used on an integer value which shows up as 0x4455FF00 in a Hex Editor like [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/de/hxd/), the Java method however returns 0x445**4**FF00.

Oddly enough, `getShortValue()` is correct with 0x4455 and getByteValue() obviously as well.

Why does it differ? What went wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Why are you reimplementing `DataInputStream` and/or `RandomAccessFile?`

Comment: EJP: I just forgot they existed, but thanks for pointing them out

Comment: Also, if you're using Guava, there's [`Ints.fromBytes()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#fromBytes(byte,%20byte,%20byte,%20byte))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that bytes are signed in Java (think about what happens if `getByteValue(fileOffset)` returns `-100`).

I suggest you use `ByteBuffer` and its `getInt`, `getShort` methods.

Your approach can be fixed by changing

```
public byte getByteValue(int fileOffset)
{
    return contents[fileOffset];
}
```

to

```
public int getByteValue(int fileOffset)
{
    return contents[fileOffset] & 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I chose to `wrap` a `ByteBuffer` around the array and use its functions instead of my own shifting.